# How can I get the name of procedure in Nim?

Tags: macros, nim-lang

I am trying to write a macro for debug print in the Nim language.
Currently this macro adds `filename` and`line` to the output by `instantiationInfo()`.

```
import macros  
macro debugPrint(msg: untyped): typed =
  result = quote do:
    let pos = instantiationInfo()
    echo pos.filename, ":", pos.line, ": ", `msg`

proc hello() =
  debugPrint "foo bar"
hello()
```

currently output:

```
debug_print.nim:9: foo bar
```

I would like to add the name of the procedure (or iterator) of the place where the macro was called.

desired output:

```
debug_print.nim:9(proc hello): foo bar
```

How can I get the name of procedure (or iterator) in Nim, like `__func__` in C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At runtime you can do `getFrame().procname`, but it only works with stacktrace enabled (not in release builds).

At compile-time surprisingly I can't find a way to do it. There is `callsite()` in macros module, but it doesn't go far enough. It sounds like something that might fit into the `macros.LineInfo` object.

A hacky solution would be to also use `__func__` and parse that back into the Nim proc name:

```
template procName: string =
  var name: cstring
  {.emit: "`name` = __func__;".}
  ($name).rsplit('_', 1)[0]
```

Comment: some adjustment is needed, eg: for `proc bar_baz()` I got: `bar_baz_9c8JPzPvtM9azO6OB23bjc3Q_3` (NOTE the trailing _3 when multiple functions are are in a module, and the leading `_` if function name contains underscore)

Answer (score 2):

building on answer from @def-  but making it more robust to handle edge cases of functions containing underscores, and hashes containing trailing _N or not
also using more unique names as otherwise macro would fail if proc defines a variable `name`

```nim
import strutils

proc procNameAux*(name:cstring): string =
  let temp=($name).rsplit('_', 2)
    #CHECKME: IMPROVE; the magic '4' chosen to be enough for most cases
    # EG: bar_baz_9c8JPzPvtM9azO6OB23bjc3Q_3
  if temp.len>=3 and temp[2].len < 4:
    ($name).rsplit('_', 2)[0]
  else:
    # EG: foo_9c8JPzPvtM9azO6OB23bjc3Q
    ($name).rsplit('_', 1)[0]

template procName*: string =
  var name2: cstring
  {.emit: "`name2` = __func__;".}
  procNameAux(name2)

proc foo_bar()=
  echo procName # prints foo_bar

foo_bar()
```

NOTE: this still has some issues that trigger in complex edge cases, see https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/8212